# Extension of norm operator

Tags: spacing, operator-space

[image: On the left the norm given by the command <code>\norm{\hat{A}}</code> while on the right there is the result I would like to get, even if, in my opinion, it's still quite wide on the upper part]

Hi everyone. 
It's been a while since I find issues with norm operator; I can call it like `\norm{\hat{A}},\lVert\hat{A}\rVert,\|\hat{A}\|` and even if I try to set the extension manually, such as with `\Big\Vert\hat{A}\Big\Vert`, in every single case there is a lot of unuseful bottom space that I don't want and that creates a mess in the document. In the image uploaded I tried to create, using Paint, the result that I would like to have, even if it's not perfect.
Somebody can help? I would be really grateful!
Thanks
Rob

Comment: I'd simply use `\lVert\hat{A}\rVert`. There is no need that the fences also cover the accent.

Comment: @egreg I like all the math operators to include the whole integrity of the symbols I put in them, it is a personal taste. What I asked is anyway a very specific example, but the problem I exposed is really annoying in a variety of situations; try for example `\norm{A_i\underset{i\neq j}{=}B_i}` and will appear a lot of unuseful space up there!

Comment: @Rob all delimiters are centred on the math axis so stretch as much down as up, that design is deeply embedded in TeX's math layout rules, so the space you see is not "unuseful space" it is the natural consequence of your preference to stretch the delimiter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I expected that it was a natural consequence as you said, but remains the fact that if I want, just as an example, to write `\norm{\hat{A}}` in the course of an argumentation, I mess up all the spacing between lines, so I was looking for a "compromise" in a way

Comment: You could use a larger symbol, and raise it back closer to the baseline with raisebox, say `\raisebox{2pt}{$\bigl\Vert$}` or whatever size and raise amount you want. Perhaps with Vert it wouldn't look too bad but with other delimiters, such as (A), taking them off axis like that tends to look pretty bad.

Comment: It's quite a long code, but `\raisebox{2pt}{$\lVert$}\hat{A}\raisebox{2pt}{$\rVert$}` seems to work pretty well; the only problem is that I should set the height and proportion case by case, but better than nothing! Thanks

Comment: @Rob How do you cope with `\lVert{\hat{b}\rVert+\lVert\hat{y}\rVert`, then?

Comment: @egreg `\lVert{\hat{y}\rVert` is perfect for me, but I can't say the same for `\lVert{\hat{b}\rVert`

Comment: This is maybe a stupid question, but where is `\norm` defined?

Comment: @Rob so you’re happy if in one and the same formula you have fences with different alignment? Sorry, not my idea of good typesetting. Fences should be as short as bossible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton What do you mean?

Comment: @egreg I think is not more important that every element of a file follows the same typesetting rule, but that symbols are always clear, self-explaining and optimized in space-saving. This is just my approach and I'm aware that sometimes can go against some conventional typesetting rules. But I'm a passionate about good handwriting too, so I do ask you one question: if you were writing `\norm{\hat{A}}` by your hand and your want your norm symbol to completely include the inside operator, like it's eating it, or is taking care of it in way, would you put all this space in the page?

Comment: @Rob -- I would like to look at the definition of `\norm`, but I don't know where to look.  It is unknown without any packages when using either `article` or `amsart`.  I remember that one might have been defined as an example with a model article distributed with AMS journal packages (I know that `\abs` was there, but `\abs` didn't behave the way you show, and `\norm` wouldn't have either).  So I want to see the definition of what you're using, and preferably, in what package it's defined.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think the package I'm using in which `norm` is defined, is`physics`, but I have same spacing problems also with `\lVert \rVert` or `\| \|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scalerel` package can do this.  However, because it stretches to match the argument's footprint, there is a certain inconsistency, as the argument's height changes from use to use. (1st line)

The `\stretchto` alternative on the 2nd line may provide a desired compromise

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
$\Vert\hat{A}\Vert$
$\Big\Vert\hat{A}\Big\Vert$
$\stretchleftright{\Vert}{\hat{A}}{\Vert}$
$\stretchleftright{\Vert}{g}{\Vert}$

$\stretchto{\Vert}{12pt}\hat{A}\stretchto{\Vert}{12pt}$
$\stretchto{\Vert}{12pt}g\stretchto{\Vert}{12pt}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, one could extend the verts a small distance up and down, for aesthetic purposes, here 0.5pt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\mynorm[1]{\stretchleftright{\Vert}
  {\ensurestackMath{\addstackgap[.5pt]{#1}}}{\Vert}}
\begin{document}
$\mynorm{\hat{A}}$
$\mynorm{gX}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like `\stretchleftright{\Vert}{\hat{A}}{\Vert}` the most, but the norm symbol doesn't include `\hat{A}` exactly. It is anyway very close to what I'm looking for, so thanks!

Comment: @Rob.  What is the desire?  For the vert to go both a little higher and a little lower?

Comment: @Rob Please see my edit.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes (I don't know if the tag of your name worked) remains the doubt I was exposing in the other comments and so the fact that with this approach I should adapt to every possible case. For example take `\norm{A_i\underset{i\neq j}{=}B_i}`, that has a lot of space in the upper part: if I understood well this time I should create a new command specifically for this situation. Anyway, I understood that maybe there is no other way, so I really thank you for giving me these methods.